# Is this selector wrong or inefficient?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is just a quick question, but let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li>Hi</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is it wrong or inefficient to style my CSS like this?

```
.header ul li { font-size: 12px; }
```

I believe I have read previously that it is not recommended, and yet it seems to be the cleanest way to style my HTML and CSS.

Comment: If you want to select that particular element and no other li's in the document, then this is the right way to go about it. Otherwise if you're going for "all LI elements in my document" then just use the li element selector.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that it's wrong or inefficient? It's alright for me.

Comment: Not just wrong, but better in most cases, and plus I think you need to learn more about css specificity...

Comment: I can't seem to find the link to where I read it was wrong, but all CSS guidelines I read don't seem to describe it as best practice and instead recommend specifying specific names for each element: http://cssguidelin.es/

Comment: @JamesWillson I think it's about performance, if I'm not wrong, it's slightly better to use specific names for the parser. But it's longer / annoying for you to adapt and change your HTML later on in some case, it's really not an important point to deal with.

Comment: you could just reduce the selector specificity with `.header li`

Comment: Yes I think that's what I read, from a page rendering scenario it is less efficient

Comment: It's correct if it minimally identifies the elements you want to style. Do you need "all li descendants of ul elements"? Would any li elements do? Would "all children of ul elements"? be more appropriate? Same with descendents of elements with class "header". Only consider performance when you've accurately identified the elements to be styled.

Comment: It would be "inefficient", if you had an element with defined `id`, and set the rule like `.header ul li#myId`. I've quoted inefficient because that's not even the right word to use here.

Comment: It's worth it reading this: [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: checkout SMACSS or BEM methodologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not quote what you read so I am *guessing* that you read something about "Using Efficient CSS Selectors". This <del>is</del> was one of the [Page Speed Insights recommendations](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules); and seems like this recommendation has been removed.

As far I remember, this rule encourages to write as short selectors as possible*. For the given markup, it is more efficient to say *all list items inside the header*:

```
.header li { }
```

instead of saying *all list items inside the unordered list inside the header*:

```
.header ul li { }
```

In fact, you could use shorter rules if possible:

```
.header { /* children inherit the inheritable properties */ }
li      { /* affects all list items, use if all must be styled similarly */ }
```

---

* As far as I remember, the PageSpeed documentation said that the browser matches CSS rules from bottom to top. For a rule such as:

```
li { color: red; }
```

It can simply apply red color when it encounters a list item. While, for a rule such as:

```
.header ul li { }
```

the browser has to go *up* the document tree when it encounters a list item, checking if one of the parents is an unordered list, one whose parents has the `.header` class. Browser has to check all the parents of list item until a match is found or it reaches the document element. This is inefficient.

This rule has been removed from PageSpeed recommendations so perhaps browsers have found efficient ways to handle inefficient selectors.

Comment: for the benefit of OP you could also explain _why_ it's better